# Combining two single dimensional arrays in a 2D array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having two 1D arrays. I want to convert these 2 arrays as single 2D array.

My code is:

```
public Static void Main()
{
int[] arrayRow;
int[] arrayCol;
  for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
  {
   for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
     {
       int[,] myArray = new int[row,column];
       myArray[i,j] = arrayRow[i]; // not possible -- your suggestions           
     }
   }
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
  {
   for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
     {
       Console.Write(myArray[i,j]);         
     }
   }
}
```

I need to save `arrayRow[]` and `arrayCol[]` in `myArray[,]`.

For example,

if we have `arrayRow[]={1,2,3}` and `arrayCol[]={4,5,6}` then myArray[,]={(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)}

Note: `arrayRow` and `arrayCol` may have different lengths. In such cases the element that have no pair should be stored in the new single dimensional array `result[]`.

Comment: What do you mean by "not possible"? Additionally, it's not clear what transformation you actually want to apply. For example, if you had `arrayRow = { 1, 3, 5 }` and `arrayCol = { 2, 6, 8 }` what would you want the result to be?

Comment: result is myArray={ (1,2),(3,6),(5,8)}

Comment: So you *always* want it to be an `int[arrayRow.length][2]`? What if `arrayRow` and `arrayCol` are different lengths?

Comment: yes they are of different lengths that dynamically produced from previous implementations result. 0 will be appended for if element does not exist

Comment: So what would you want to *do* with them in that case? Basically you need to make your question *much* clearer. We shouldn't have to play 20 questions to understand what you're trying to achieve. See http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't tryed this, and I'm just guessing what you want to acomplish, but here it is:

```
int[] arrayRow;
int[] arrayCol;

int[,] myArray = new int[Math.Max(arrayRow.Length, arrayCol.Length), 2];

for (int i = 0; i < arrayRow.Length; i++)
  myArray[i, 0] = arrayRow[i];

for (int i = 0; i < arrayCol.Length; i++)
  myArray[i, 1] = arrayCol[i];
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `arrayRow[]` and `arrayCol[]` will be just two lines of a two-dimensional array (if you didn't mean jagged one).

So the code to unite two arrays into one is just:

```
public static T[,] Union<T>(T[] first, T[] second) //where T : struct
{
    T[,] result = new T[2, Math.Max(first.Length, second.Length)];
    int firstArrayLength = first.Length * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
    Buffer.BlockCopy(first, 0, result, 0, firstArrayLength);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(second, 0, result, firstArrayLength, second.Length * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)));
    return result;
}
```

As [it have been mentinoned](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/5d525b76-f5b6-4340-a899-c3c82570d2e1#4fd0199f-ca1a-40be-90b0-c5c31208e105), `BlockCopy` is cooler than `for` cycle.

---

If you **do** mean that you need a jagged array (like `int[][]`), that the solutiona will be way more simplier:

```
public static T[][] UnionJagged<T>(T[] first, T[] second)
{
    return new T[2][] { first, second };
}
```

Which transforms into even simplier if we add multiple-array-as-parameters functionality:

```
public static T[][] UnionJagged<T>(params T[][] arrays)
{
    return arrays;
}

static void Main()
{
    int[] a = new int[] { 10, 2, 3 };
    int[] b = new int[] { -1, 2, -3 };
    int[] c = new int[] { 1, -2, 3 };
    int[][] jaggedThing = UnionJagged(a, b, c);
}
```

Comment: +1, I agree with you, but I don't think OP is currently capable to experiment with all advanced techniques.

Answer (score 0):

More performant / another way:

```
public static void ConvertFlatArrayToMatrix(int[] array, int[,] matrix, int dimension) {
        for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
            int r = Mathf.FloorToInt(i / dimension);
            int c = i % dimension;

            matrix[c,r] = array[i];
        }
    }
```

This will just push the result into a 2d array you pass in.

Keep in mind, I'm not checking length or protecting against anything here, this is just the concept and the bare minimum to get the job done.